# How to read numbers in a line into variables AND tuples in python

Tags: python

I have a file that contains a numbers in a single line like so:

```
6 10 11 2 23 37
```

The fourth number , represents how many numbers remain in the line. (the fourth number is 2 and the remaining two numbers are 23 and 27)

I know that I can assign individual integers to variable this way

```
a, b, c, d = map(int, line.split())
```

How do I read this file in python so that I can read the first four numbers into variables and the remaining numbers into tuples in python.

The Resulting output I want is

```
a = 6
b = 10
c = 11
d = 2
my_tuple = (23, 27)
```

What is the easiest way to go about this in python?

Answer (score 1):

Very close, just use `my_tuple` with unpacking (`*`) in the beginning:

```
a, b, c, d, *my_tuple = map(int, line.split())
```

And now:

```
print(a,b,c,d,my_tuple,sep='\n')
```

Outputs:

```
6
10
11
2
[23, 37]
```